# combine one to more tables and get the values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have created insert query for combining one to more tables and take values into single.

**Table 1:**

**CandidateQualifications:**

- Id
- CandidateId
- DegreeId
- Specialization

**Table 2:**

UG_list

- Id
- Ugname

**Table 3:**

PG_list

- Id
- pgname

**Table 4:**

Docorate_List

- Id
- Ugname

These all tables id is called to follow table,

**CandidateDetails**

- Qualification
- Postgraduation
- doctorate

It shows separate degrees in this candidatedetails table. when i use follow query i get only qualification values. others are eliminated. so if 3 degrees is there means candidateid shows 3 times. but only one time it show.

My query is,

```
SELECT top(50) 'INSERT INTO CandidateQualifications(candidateId,DegreeId,specialization) VALUES('+
 Cast(c.CandidateID as varchar(50))+',''' +
 ISNULL(Cast(Coalesce(u.Id,p.Id,d.Id)as varchar(50)),'NULL')+','+
 IsNull(''''+c.ugspecification+'''', 'NULL')+')'
  FROM  candidatedetails as c
  LEFT join UG_List As u ON c.qualification=u.UGName
  LEFT join PG_List As p ON c.PostGraduation=p.PGName
  LEFT join Docorate_List As d ON c.Doctorate=d.Doctorate
```

**Result set**

```
INSERT INTO CandidateQualifications(candidateId,DegreeId,specialization) VALUES(2,'38,'Hotel Management')

INSERT INTO CandidateQualifications(candidateId,DegreeId,specialization) VALUES(3,'17,'HMCT (Hotel Management& Catering technology)')
```

Please help me anyone to come out this problem?

Comment: anyone have idea about this?

Comment: please some provide clear information

Comment: Could you give an example, please?(test data)

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental problem in your requirement in that in your table `CandidateQualifications` you want have `DegreeID`, but you want this to link to 3 tables.

With some example data:

**CandidateDetails**

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
¦ ID ¦ Qualification  ¦ Postgraduation ¦ doctorate ¦
¦----+----------------+----------------+-----------¦
¦  1 ¦ Qualification1 ¦ PostGraduation1¦ doctorate1¦
¦  2 ¦ Qualification2 ¦ PostGraduation2¦ doctorate2¦
¦  3 ¦ Qualification3 ¦ PostGraduation3¦ doctorate3¦
+----+----------------+----------------+-----------+
```

**UG_list**

```
+---------------------+
¦ ID ¦      Ugname    ¦
¦----+----------------¦
¦  1 ¦ Qualification1 ¦ 
¦  2 ¦ Qualification2 ¦ 
¦  3 ¦ Qualification3 ¦ 
+----+----------------+
```

**PG_list**

```
+---------------------+
¦ ID ¦      pgname    ¦
¦----+----------------¦
¦  1 ¦ PostGraduation1¦ 
¦  2 ¦ PostGraduation2¦
¦  3 ¦ PostGraduation3¦ 
+----+----------------+
```

**Docorate_List**

```
+-----------------+
¦ ID ¦  dcname    ¦
¦----+------------¦
¦  1 ¦ doctorate1 ¦ 
¦  2 ¦ doctorate2 ¦
¦  3 ¦ doctorate3 ¦ 
+----+------------+
```

What it appears you are looking to end up with in `CandidateQualifications` is

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
¦ ID ¦ CandidateId  ¦ DegreeId ¦ Specialization ¦
¦----+--------------+----------+----------------¦
¦  1 ¦      1       ¦     1    ¦      Spec1     ¦  -- Qualification1
¦  2 ¦      1       ¦     1    ¦      Spec1     ¦  -- PostGraduation1
¦  3 ¦      1       ¦     1    ¦      Spec1     ¦  -- doctorate1
¦  4 ¦      2       ¦     2    ¦      Spec2     ¦  -- Qualification2
¦  5 ¦      2       ¦     2    ¦      Spec2     ¦  -- PostGraduation2
¦  6 ¦      2       ¦     2    ¦      Spec2     ¦  -- doctorate2
¦  7 ¦      3       ¦     3    ¦      Spec3     ¦  -- Qualification3
¦  8 ¦      3       ¦     3    ¦      Spec3     ¦  -- PostGraduation3
¦  9 ¦      3       ¦     3    ¦      Spec3     ¦  -- doctorate3
+----+--------------+----------+----------------+
```

The trouble is that because you have ID's from three different tables, once you have inserted the data you have no way of knowing which one it links back to.

If it is not too late I would suggest changing your data structure to something like as follows:

**QualificationType**

```
+----+---------------+
¦ ID ¦      Name     ¦
¦----+---------------¦
¦  1 ¦ UnderGraduate ¦ 
¦  2 ¦  PostGraduate ¦
¦  3 ¦   Doctorate   ¦ 
+----+---------------+
```

**Degree**

```
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
¦ ID ¦ QualificationTypeID ¦       Name      ¦
¦----+---------------------¦-----------------¦
¦  1 ¦        1            ¦  Qualifacation1 ¦
¦  2 ¦        1            ¦  Qualifacation2 ¦
¦  3 ¦        1            ¦  Qualifacation3 ¦
¦  4 ¦        2            ¦ PostGraduation1 ¦
¦  5 ¦        2            ¦ PostGraduation2 ¦
¦  6 ¦        2            ¦ PostGraduation3 ¦
¦  7 ¦        3            ¦    Doctorate1   ¦
¦  8 ¦        3            ¦    Doctorate2   ¦
¦  9 ¦        3            ¦    Doctorate3   ¦
+----+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Then your CandidateQualifation table can reference QualifationID, then you know exactly what it references.

So your insert query becomes (I am not sure where specialisation comes from):

```
INSERT CandidateQualifation (CandidateID, DegreeID)
SELECT  cd.CandidateID,
        dg.DegreeID
FROM    CandidateDetails cd
        LEFT JOIN Degree ug
            ON cd.qualification = ug.Name
            AND cd.QualificationTypeID = 1
        LEFT JOIN Degree pg
            ON cd.PostGraduation = pg.Name
            AND cd.QualificationTypeID = 2
        LEFT JOIN Degree doc
            ON cd.Doctorate = doc.Name
            AND cd.QualificationTypeID = 3
        OUTER APPLY
        (   VALUES
                (ug.ID),
                (pg.ID),
                (doc.ID)
        ) dg (DegreeID);
```

And you can get your qualifations using something like

```
SELECT  cd.CandidateID,
        Qualification = Degree.Name,
        QualificationType = qt.Name
FROM    CandidateDetails cd
        INNER JOIN CandidateQualifications cq
            ON cd.ID = cq.CandidateID
        INNER JOIN Degree
            ON Degree.ID = cq.DegreeID
        INNER JOIN QualificationType qt
            ON qt.ID = Degree.QualificationTypeID;
```

However, to answer your actual question, you can get the separate qualifations as sepearate rows using OUTER APPLY:

```
SELECT  cd.CandidateID,
        d.DegreeID
FROM    CandidateDetails cd
        LEFT JOIN UG_List
            ON cD.qualification = UG_List.UGName
        LEFT JOIN PG_List As p
            ON cd.PostGraduation = PG_List.PGName
        LEFT JOIN Docorate_List As d 
            ON cD.Doctorate = Docorate_List.Doctorate
        OUTER APPLY
        (   VALUES
                (UG_List.ID),
                (PG_List.ID),
                (UG_List.ID)
        ) d (DegreeID);
```